# Can I freeze almond/raspberry cake?

Tags: cake, freezing

I bought a raspberry almond one layer cake at a bake sale. The almonds were fine grained as in flour. My question: can I freeze this cake?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  We don't support having your entire question in the title.  I've moved it into the body of the question for you.